# How I extend params

Tags: jquery, fancybox

how i expand the params in my fancybox?
the **params** should come with the function.

```
contentOverlayBox = function(headline, content, params){
    $.fancybox({
        fitToView   : true,
        autoSize    : true,
        content     : '<strong>'+headline+'</strong><br /><br />'+content
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the object with [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) before passing it to fancybox, like so:

```
contentOverlayBox = function(headline, content, params){
    var options = {
        fitToView   : true,
        autoSize    : true,
        content     : '<strong>'+headline+'</strong><br /><br />'+content
    }

    $.extend(options, params);

    $.fancybox(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fancybox($.extend({
    fitToView   : true,
    autoSize    : true,
    content     : '<strong>'+headline+'</strong><br /><br />'+content
}, params));
```